# Calling a function in an IF statement vs not in IF statement

Tags: c++, output, line-breaks

Why when I call function inside of the if statement the result is like:

```
please enter phone number: please enter your name:
```

But I need like:

```
please enter your phone number: 4545
please enter your name: dddf
```

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void insert_data ()
{
    string phone_number[10] = {};
    string name[10] = {};

    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
        if(name[i] != "" ){
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout<< "please enter phone number: ";
    string new_phone_number;
    getline (cin, new_phone_number);
    phone_number[count] = new_phone_number;

    cout<< "please enter your name: ";
    string new_name;
    getline (cin, new_name);
    name[count] = new_name;

    count++;
}

int main()
{
    string a;
    cin>> a;
    if(a == 1){
        insert_data();
    }

}
```

Comment: Unrelated, `if(a == 1)` - that isn't valid C++ code.

Comment: That won't compile, and it should misbehave even without the conditional, because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Answer (score 3):

> " please enter phone number: please enter your name: in the same line"
>   but I need like the first "please enter your phone number: 4545 in the
>   next line please enter your name: dddf

What you need to use is `std::endl`. It stands for "end the line and flush the stream" and will insert a new line in your output. Change this:

```
cout<< "please enter your name: ";
```

To this:

```
cout << endl << "please enter your name: ";
```

To insert a new line before that line, resulting in this output:

```
please enter your phone number: 4545
please enter your name: dddf
```

Also, you should probably change this:

```
if(a == 1){
    insert_data();
}
```

To just that:

```
insert_data();
```

I'm amazed that the `if(a == 1)` even works, looking at the documentation it's probably casting the `1` to a `const char*` for string comparison. Either way it's nonsense and probably doesn't do what you intended.

Comment: unfortunately `std::endl` does not really stand for "end the line" but for "end the line and flush the stream". "end the line" is `'\n'`

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I added it to the answer.

Comment: the problem is if I will put if statement then it is not posible to give the input in from the console for the  "please enter phone number: "; And I need if statement

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in one side I used getline in another cin